# How to make right sidebar sticky in jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, blogger

I need jQuery code for the sticky right sidebar in blogger. This sidebar should stop at the footer, but it's not. It should stick at a specific scroll, so the user can see the content on the sidebar.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var offset = $(".column-right-inner").offset();
            var topPadding = 15;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $(".column-right-inner").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $(".column-right-inner").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: i'd suggest against using an animation for this. Since this event is occurring frequently during the scroll,  you can just set the value on each event. Even better would be to skip controlling the position entirely and just add/remove stickyness as needed and let the browser handle the positioning.

Comment: jQuery `1.3.2`? ... must it really be that low of a version?

Comment: You should show the page markup and style as well if you want useful replies.

Comment: Agree with @KevinB but also triggering `$(window).scroll(...` can cause some jerkiness/oddities. I've used https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/ to much success